# Should I put my Degree or the general Field on my business card?

Tags: job-search, business-cards

I'm just graduating with my Masters in Information Systems and starting my big job hunt and am unsure whether or not I should put "M.S. Information Systems" or just put "Information Systems" on my personal business card?

Background: I'm looking for jobs in both security and UX and what I do currently is IT support, but that's not what I went back to college for nor what I want to end up doing.

Related: [Is there a canonical reference for business cards?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/536/is-there-a-canonical-reference-for-business-cards)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a canonical reference for business cards?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/536/is-there-a-canonical-reference-for-business-cards)

Answer (score 2):

I've been doing this for 50 years, and I've seen thousands of business cards. I can’t remember  seeing one with a person's degree field on it. Someone that has your card has it for a reason, and knows what is your field.

I know you've just completed a rigorous academic program, but there are lots of MS programs out there that have little content, and therefore, there are lots of people with MS and MBA degrees. When you refer to your degree, do it in a context where you can demonstrate that you’ve been through a rigorous program, and why that  makes you more qualified than someone else. Elaborate on  your degree  in your Vita. There you have room to go into a bit of detail, and explain your qualifications.

On your business card, just:

John Smith, MS (or Ph.D, or RPE, or whatever)

Be sure there's a QR code on the back of your card that will take the recipient to a web page that shows your qualifications in detail. I’ve got 2 QR codes on the back of my card. One is an eCard and one is a URL that takes you to my web page. **VERY** important is the  no-nonsense appearance, spelling , and grammar of your web page.

You’re at an exciting time in your life.  Your concern with detail is a very good sign. I envy you and wish you the very best of luck.

Comment: I did originally just have my web URL on my initial business card design, I was originally hoping that MOO would finally have released their NFC business cards, but they seem to still be in development. I'll take the QR code under advisement.