# Student business card

Tags: job-search, student, business-cards

I'm currently on a first year of my Masters (computer science).
Currently working as a student in a global software company (not sure if I'm allowed to name it).

Regardless of that, I'm actively seeking another employment opportunities and for that reason I plan to make business cards to use at some social events, conferences etc.

My question is, what should I place on my business card?
Full name, email, GitHub link, linkedIn link...

As an representative of a tech company, what would you like to see on a student's business card?

Comment: Likely duplicate of [Is there a canonical reference for business cards?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/536/is-there-a-canonical-reference-for-business-cards?noredirect=1&lq=1). That question could use an edit (and some more answers) but it also about the content of business cards for soon-to-be-graduates.

Comment: "Consultant," according to Liz Ryan, who writes an advice column for Forbes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A student handing out business cards would seem presumptuous to many people.

But in general at low levels clean and factual is better than ornate and messy. So if you must I suggest, Name, Degree (abbreviated), Title (if any) & Contact details. The main point of a business card in your situation would be to give your contact details rather than advertising.